# Ubuntu docker passwd: Authentication token manipulation error passwd: password unchanged

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

In Ubuntu docker file am trying to add a new user and trying to change the password for that user. So for that I am using below script in the docker

[image]

When I am running this script through docker, I am getting an error like

`Enter new UNIX passord: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error passwd: password unchanged`

I have tried to used ${owner} instead of udev like this

`echo "${owner}:udev" | chpasswd`

but still its not working, getting the same error again.
So can someone please help me where to fix this issue?

FYI, I am using ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks,

Comment: A Docker container runs a single process, not an interactive login session, and there's no way to "log into" it.  Delete the `chpasswd` invocation entirely.  (You also do not need `sudo`.)

Comment: So you are telling there is no need of this line?
`echo "${owner}:udev" | chpasswd`

Comment: Correct, you should be able to just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the password of the user `udev` to the string `udev`, try this :

```
printf "udev\nudev\n" | passwd udev
```